# Добавление ID в DIV через JQUERY

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. Ломаю голову уже который час.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = $(".post-image > a > img").length;
    if (count > 2) {
        $("#inline").attr("id", "clear");
    }
}
```

Скрипт считает количество картинок в блоке. Если больше двух, то текст не обтекает картинки, а переносит его на новую строку. ID не заменяется, в чем проблема-то?

Comment: Плохая идея использовать для этого id, сделайте классами с помощью addClass.

Comment: @kosost, не подскажете, как добавить еще один класс к классу, а не заменить его?
Было так: <div class="post-image">, стало так: <div class="post-image clear">, например.

Comment: addClass и не заменяет, чтобы заменить, надо удалить старый с помощью removeClass.

Comment: `
$(document).ready(function(){
 var count = $(".post-image > a").length;
 if (count > 3) {
  $('.post-image').css('border', '1px solid red');
 }
});

`
Сделал так, бордер добавляется ко всем элементам, независимо от количества картинок. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @GreenMonster, В считаете кол-во ссылок, а не изображений. И опишите словами то, что вы хотите получить в итоге.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспроизвел [Ваш код на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpkony9n/), все прекрасно работает, можете поизменять maxImage и убедиться.

Вы все-таки потрудитесь добавить разметку HTML, CSS и посмотреть в консоль на предмет того, нет ли там ошибок. А еще в дополнение ко всему, можно локализовать ошибку с помощью логирования участков кода через console.log(), что значительно упростит поиск неисправного участка. А еще хорошо сделать пример на том же jsfiddle, который будет имитировать проблемный участок.

Comment: Возможно, дело в конфликте библиотек jquery на моем сайте, но уже все починили, переписав скрипт.

За console.log() спасибо, буду теперь пользоваться.